Azure mysql not logging full query
I have a web API using entity framework and C#. I wanted to log slow queries in Azure mysql coming from this service. Below are the server parameters set
slow_query_log = ON
long_query_time = 2
log_output  = FILE
log_queries_not_using_indexes = OFF

When I look into the log, it has logged one query but it is not complete.
SELECT `a`.`Id`, `a`.`AccommodationCompanyId`, `a`.`ActiveOffers`,`a`.`PropertyName`, `a`.`SortOrder`, `a`.`Status`, `a`.`Step`, `a`.`booking_tc`, `a`.`booking_tc_url`, `c`.`Id`, `c`.`DateCreated`, `c`.`DateUpdated`, `c`.`Description`, `c`.`Image`, `c`.`IsFeatured`, `c`.`Message`, `c`.`Name`, `c`.`SortOrder`, `c`.`Status`, `a0`.`Id`, `a0`.`AccommodationId`, `a0`.`DateCreated`, `a0`.`DateUpdated`, `a0`.`Distance`, `a0`.`Status`, `a0`.`UniversityId`, `a1`.`Id`, `a1`.`AccommodationId`, `a1`.`DateCreated`, `a1`.`DateUpdated`, `a1`.`FacilityId`, `a1`.`Status`, `a2`.`Id`, `a2`.`AccommodationId`, `a2`.`DateCreated`, `a2`.`DateUpdated`, `a2`.`EndDate`, `a2`.`OfferId`, `a2`.`StartDate`, `a2`.`Status`, `a3`.`Id`, `a3`.`AccommodationId`, `a3`.`AccommodationRoomTypeId`, `a3`.`AllowedDeposit`, `a3`.`Commission`, `a3`.`DateCreated`, `a3`.`DateUpdated`, `a3`.`Description`, `a3`.`IndividualPagePromotion`, `a3`.`IsSummer`,`a3`.`Name`, `a3`.`Quantity`, `a3`.`Rent`, `a3`.`Status`
FROM `accommodations` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN `cities` AS `c` ON `a`.`CityId` = `c`.`Id`
LEFT JOIN `accommodations_universities` AS `a0` ON `a`.`Id` = `a0`.`AccommodationId`
LEFT JOIN `accommodation_facilities` AS `a1` ON `a`.`Id` = `a1`.`AccommodationId`
LEFT JOIN;

Obviously the LEFT JOIN should have been there for table aliases a2 and a3
The API has given results so the C# code has certainly executed the query in full but it is the log that is not showing the complete query. Where is it going wrong?
I tried changing log_queries_not_using_indexes to ON and also max_allowed_packet from 16777216 to 64777216 as suggested by ChatGpt but nothing helps.

You really should be asking DBAs and not programmers about this issue as it is not a programming problem, but either a database config issue or a bug in mysql.

Consider posting the complete query that was submitted to the optimizer.
